# How to increase the quality of a recorded voice?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, trim, avaudiorecorder

I have to merge the audio file and recorded voice.For example, the recorded voice is 47seconds. I have to cut or trim the 4minutes audio song to 47seconds. And merge the audio file.It's working fine now.If I hear once I merged both.. My voice is very low and Music is very high.How to increase the Voice quality?I attached the audio recorder settings also:

```
func mixAudio()
{
    let currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    compositionAudioTrack.preferredVolume = 0.8
    print(soundFileURL)
    do {

}

catch _
{
}
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset.init(URL: soundFileURL, options: nil)
    print("\(avAsset)")
    var tracks = avAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    let clipAudioTrack = tracks[0]
    do {
        try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration), ofTrack: clipAudioTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    }
    catch _
    {
    }
    let compositionAudioTrack1 = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    compositionAudioTrack1.preferredVolume = 0.8
    let avAsset1 = AVURLAsset.init(URL: soundFileURL1)
    print(avAsset1)
            var tracks1 = avAsset1.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    let clipAudioTrack1 = tracks1[0]
    do {
        try compositionAudioTrack1.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset1.duration), ofTrack: clipAudioTrack1, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    }
    catch _ {
    }
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let CachesDirectory = paths[0]
    let strOutputFilePath = CachesDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/Fav")
    print(" strOutputFilePath is \n \(strOutputFilePath)")

    let requiredOutputPath = CachesDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/Fav.m4a")
    print(" requiredOutputPath is \n \(requiredOutputPath)")

    soundFile1 = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(requiredOutputPath)
    print(" OUtput path is \n \(soundFile1)")
    let audioDuration = avAsset.duration
    let totalSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration)
    let hours = Int64(totalSeconds / 3600)
    let minutes = Int64(totalSeconds % 3600 / 60)
    let seconds = Int64(totalSeconds % 3600 % 60)
    print("hours = \(hours), minutes = \(minutes), seconds = \(seconds)")
    print(soundFile1)
    let recordSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [

        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue
    ]
    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFile1, settings: recordSettings)
        audioRecorder!.delegate = self
        audioRecorder!.meteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder!.prepareToRecord()
    }

    catch let error as NSError
    {
        audioRecorder = nil
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    do {

        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(soundFile1)
    }
    catch _ {
    }
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    exporter!.outputURL = soundFile1
    exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(avAsset1.duration)
    print(duration)
    if (duration < 5.0) {
        print("sound is not long enough")
        return
    }
    // e.g. the first 30 seconds
    let startTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1)
    let stopTime = CMTimeMake(seconds,1)
    let exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime)
    print(exportTimeRange)
    exporter!.timeRange = exportTimeRange
    print(exporter!.timeRange)


    exporter!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler
        {() -> Void in
            print(" OUtput path is \n \(requiredOutputPath)")
            print("export complete: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - currentTime)")
            var url:NSURL?
            if self.audioRecorder != nil
            {
                url = self.audioRecorder!.url
            }

            else
            {
                url = self.soundFile1!
                print(url)

            }

            print("playing \(url)")

    do
    {
        print(self.soundFile1)
        print(" OUtput path is \n \(requiredOutputPath)")


        let session:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("could not set session category")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        do {
            // try session.setActive(true)
        } catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("could not make session active")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        do
        {

        }
        self.PlayerWithHeadphone = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: self.soundFile1)
        self.PlayerWithHeadphone.numberOfLoops = 0
        self.PlayerWithHeadphone.volume = 2.0
        self.PlayerWithHeadphone.play()
    }
    catch _
    {

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: `My voice is very low and Music is very high` Because the two files you're using have different levels, you could normalize the levels before merging. Give gain to the file with voice, and remove gain to the file with music, then merge. Ideally both would not peak at more than -9 dbFS before merging.

Comment: Actually the voice url is .m4a format and song is .mp3 format..I merge the both and get the final merged sound..Is there any issue?